# Why SpringBootTests do not invoke main method of SpringBootApplication class

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to figure out why this is happening. My `main()` method contains some initialization procedures that are vital for application startup and spring boot integration tests are not invoking it.
Can someone pls explain this behavior.

Comment: Can you show your main class

Comment: It's a regular SpringBoot app, nothing special about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot test does not need call `SpringBootApplication.main()` because it scans pacakes for configurations by himself. It tries to mimic the processes that use Spring Boot framework for creating the context. In other words it scans based on package structures, loads external configurations from predefined locations, optionally runs auto-configuration starters and so on. Interesting this is that If you just put `@SpringBootTest` on your test class, scanning process will be done on packages in up direction

Example:
For following project structure

```
└── com
    └── example
        └── demo
            ├── config
            │   └── AppConfig.java
            ├── test
            |   └── SpringBootAppTest.java
            └── DemoApplication.java
```

Spring Boot test will search for `SpringBootConfiguration` in:

1. `com.example.demo.test`
2. `com.example.demo`
3. `com.example`
4. `com`

So when it will find `SpringBootApplication` (which is `SpringBootConfiguration`) it is load it's context that scan for other configuration and beans in another direction in sample case `com.example.demo.configuration` . Therefore all context will be loaded.

If you for example move `SpringBootAppTest` up to `com.example` it will fail (because `SpringBootApplication` can't be found) with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```